# How to set the size of an image within CKeditor in Ruby On Rails according to the picture model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, paperclip

**This could be a duplicate question but I doubt it.**

**I have the following situation:**

I have a ruby on rails apllication with two widely used gems: paperclip and ckeditor (which is working with paperclip).

I want the size of the image that I upload in the Ckeditor screen to be resized depending on the type of 'post'. Right now there's not a button that can help with that in the Ckeditor or anything, though it does upload the different type of sizes I set in the picture.rb model:

```
class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
  has_attached_file :data,
                :url  => "/ckeditor_assets/pictures/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
                :path => ":rails_root/public/ckeditor_assets/pictures/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
                :styles => { :content => '600>',:medium => '300x300', :quintet => '150x150', :thumb => '118x100#' }


  validates_attachment_size :data, :less_than => 2.megabytes
  validates_attachment_presence :data


  def url_content
    url(:content)
  end
end
```

The problem is that the content (images and tags) that gets saved from the Ckeditor will be displayed like

```
.post_body= raw post.content
```

where post.content =

```
 <p><img alt="" src="/ckeditor_assets/pictures/2/content_cartoon_paul-the-good-fight.gif" /></p>
```

The image that the CKeditor is using is the standard image and not the image with a certain size or type.
How do I set that size or type?

Answer (score 0):

In the url_content method, replace :content with the style you require (e.g., :medium, :quintet, :thumb). Note that for any images uploaded BEFORE you set a specific style, there will be no corresponding image of that size. Any image uploaded will get different versions saved to the ckeditor_assets path (e.g., original, medium, thumb) and then you can change the url parameter to point to the correct version. It took me a while to realize this since I was testing with an already uploaded picture, so when testing if it works, make sure all the styles you want are specified and then upload a new picture. Changing the parameter for url_content should work then.